# Nginx won't serve assets for www.mydomain.com, but serves for mydomain.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

There is nothing in acess/error logs for www.* assets.

```
upstream unicorn {
        server 127.0.0.1:5000;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com xn--n3h.net;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

                # If you don't find the filename in the static files
                # Then request it from the unicorn server
                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                        proxy_pass http://unicorn;
                        break;
                }
        }
}
```

So if I access http://mydomain.com everything works fine, but if I access www.domain.com browser just loads html page and won't load any asset (css, js, etc...). WTF? Am I missing something? Path to assets in HTML is absolute without any domain (just "/assets/style.css" for example).

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
config.serve_static_assets = true

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
config.assets.compress = true

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = true

# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true
```

Using unicorn.

Comment: Don't know Nginx very well, but wouldn't you also need to add a rewrite similar to the one you have for xn--n3h.net for the www variant?

Comment: xn--n3h.net should work (and it works) without any rewrite.

Comment: So you don't need a redirect like `rewrite ^/(http://xn--n3h.net/ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 permanent;` - and you have tried adding one?

Comment: Post updated, rewrite rule removed. This was my experiments that should not be there at all. Never mind.

Comment: Is the `www` DNS set up correctly? You mention nothing in the logs...

Comment: It was stupid DNS issue, admin failed arghhhh. Thanks.